# Given $a_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{n^2}e^{k/n^2}$, find $a,b\in\Bbb R$ with $ \lim_{n\to\infty}(na_n-an)=b$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

> It is given that:
>
> $$a_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{n^2} e^{\frac{k}{n^2}}$$
>
> and $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} a_n=\frac{1}{2}$. I want to find reals
>   $a,b$ so $ \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} (n a_n-a n)=b $.

Actually I was wondering if there is a theorem such as Stolz-Cesaro to solve it. I can't find something. Thank you

Comment: You made me look up *hind* in the dictionary. I don't think that's what you meant.

Comment: I correct the mistake

Comment: Since $b$ is finite, we need $a=\frac{1}{2}$. But we need more information to uniquely determine $b$. If $a_n=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n}$, we get $b=0$. If $a_n=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n^2}$, we get $b=0$. If $a_n=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n}$, we get $b=-1$ a.s.o.

Comment: why do you assume the cases $a_n=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n}$ and $a_n=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n^2}$ etc. How do you calculate $b?$

Comment: That's the point. We can not uniquely calculate $b$, if we're only given that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}a_n=\frac{1}{2}$, because for different sequences that tend to $\frac{1}{2}$ (which I've given as examples) we get different values for $b$.

Comment: actually $a_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{n^2} e^{\frac{k}{n^2}}$

Comment: that changes everything. Edit the question and include all the necessary information.

Answer (score 3):

In fact it's not hard to get the complete asymptotics:
\begin{align}a_n&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k}{n^2}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{m!}\left(\frac{k}{n^2}\right)^m=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{n^{-2m-2}}{m!}\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{m+1}\\&=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{n^{-m}}{m!(m+2)}\sum_{r=0}^{m+1}\binom{m+2}{r}(-1)^r B_r n^{-r},\end{align} where the last equality is obtained using [Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula). Collecting powers of $n$, we rewrite this as \begin{align}a_n&=\sum_{s=0}^{\infty}n^{-s}\color{blue}{\sum_{r=0}^{\lceil s/2\rceil}\frac{(-1)^r(s-r+1)}{r!(s-2r+2)!}B_r}\\&=\underbrace{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{5}{6n}}_{\text{asked for}}+\frac{5}{8n^2}+\frac{9}{20n^3}+\frac{31}{144n^4}+\frac{391}{5040n^5}+\ldots\end{align}